# C++ and preprocessor macro gotcha

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Can you figure out what is wrong with the statement below?

GCC error states:

> 'type name' declared as function returning array

```
#define MACRO(a) (a)[1]

class index {
public:
    typedef int index_type[2];
    const index_type& operator[](int i) const;
};

int k = 0;
int i = MACRO(index()[k]);
```

btw: I know what is wrong, I thought it was amusing thing to share.   Many thanks to litb, his explanation of previous gotcha helped to solve this error pretty quickly.

Comment: sorry, I messed up previous post

Comment: You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2741790/edit) them

Comment: That code compiles for me in Visual C++ 2008 (though I had to change `class` to `struct` to make the members public... adding `public:` at the top would've done the same thing). I assume you get the error on the `int i = MACRO(...` line?

Comment: I would just add that I hope you're not planning on use this sort of code in a real situation!

Comment: Hm, works in VS, doesn't work in gcc. Strange. I don't see why it should be failing. Also, *why on Earth is this being down-voted?*

Comment: @codeka yes.  you should be getting error, unless I messed up again.
maybe VS is not standard compliant?  the above example is simplified snippet of code useful to me

Comment: It's fixed if you changed the macro to #define MACRO(a) a[1], but I don't know enough C++ syntax to understand why, so if somebody can run with that and post an answer, go for it

Comment: @GMan by the way, this is cw because I know answer ( took me some time to find) and I thought it was amusing

Comment: @aaa: Ah, I see. Well I can't wait to see then, because I don't see it. :X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expanded line:

```
int i = (index()[k])[1];
```

`(index()[k])` is interpreted as a cast expression, declaring a function that returns an array of length `k` of index. At least, that's what it looks like is happening. How gcc is manages to validly interpret the `[1]` as an expression, I'm not sure.

Comment: Intel compiler and visual C++ compile.  I think they use the same front-end

Comment: @aaa:  The Intel C++ Compiler uses the EDG frontend; Microsoft Visual C++ uses its own frontend.  They are entirely unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be there's an ambiguity in your syntax. The compiler might be looking at the expanded macro:

```
 int i = (index()[k])[1];
```

And thinking that `index` is actually a non-member function declaration that returns an array, rather than construction of a temporary object of *type* `index`.

But that's just a guess... if you know the answer already, please enlighten us :)

Comment: yes, that is what is happening (well, at least this is how i explained it).

Comment: By the way, I think this would explain why Visual C++ can compile it and still be considered "standards compliant". With an ambiguous syntax, the compiler can choose to interpret it either way and still be considered "standards compliant" :)

Comment: am afraid to think that somewhere in standard such behavior is defined.

Answer (score 1):

When you apply your macro, it expands to:

```
class index 
{
    // ...
    typedef int index_type[2];
    const index_type& operator[](int i)const;
    // ...
};

int k = 0;
int i = (index()[k])[1];
```

Now the problem (assuming that index::operator[] is public, and it is non-obvious from your code snippet that it is) is that the result of index::operator[] is returned by reference, and you are constructing the index() object as a temporary, and so, assuming your index::operator[] is implemented how I'm guessing you've implemented it (returning a reference to a member object), the result of index::operator[] will be invalid immediately after it is returned (as the temporary is destructed), and so you have undefined behavior.

Comment: my thoughts at first. but not quite the answer.  I put const qualifier to disambiguate

Comment: @aaa, it is still a reference, even with a const qualifier.

Comment: There isn't any undefined behavior in the presented code. (Which wouldn't explain the error anyway.) Returning a reference to a member would be fine, the temporary lives until the end of the full expression.

Comment: @GMan, you are right. That's a typo.

Comment: your preprocessor expansion is not quite right.  the syntax error is hidden in there.  okay, now it's right.